# Select elements in a list of tuples of quaternions that satisfy a condition

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, quaternions, tuples

I defined 24 quaternions using the Quaternions package and i create the list of all possible 4-tuples using

```
ListQuad = Tuples[ListQuaternions, 4]
```

where `ListQuaternions` is the list of the 24 elements I defined.
Now I would like to select all the 4-tuples such that the product of the four quaternions is equal to `Quaternion[1, 0, 0, 0]`.

I tried to use this:

```
Select[ListQuad,{x_, y_, z_, w_} /; x ** y ** z ** w == Quaternion[1, 0, 0, 0] &]
```

but this gives me an empty list, which I'm sure it can't be true because I know that some 4-tuples satisfy that condition.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Probably the condition I put in the `Select` command?

Comment: You might want to use `Select[ListQuad, (x ** y ** z ** w == Quaternion[1, 0, 0, 0]) &]` instead. In general, you have to decide whether to use `Select` (function based selection) or `Cases` (pattern based selection).

Comment: I tried also the solution you wrote me but it still gives me an empty list. probably there is something wrong in the definition of the list. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henrik has already mentioned `Select[]` and `Cases[]`. For this answer, I'll show how to use `Pick[]`:

```
<< Quaternions`

ListQuaternions = UnitQuaternions;
ListQuad = Tuples[ListQuaternions, {4}];

prods = NonCommutativeMultiply @@@ ListQuad;

sel = Pick[quads, Map[Norm, prods - Quaternion[1, 0, 0, 0]], 0];

{Length[ListQuad], Length[sel]}
   {331776, 13824}
```

The slightly complicated condition in `Pick[]` is necessitated by the fact that `Equal` (`==`) cannot handle quaternions; e.g. `Quaternion[1, 0, 0, 0] == Quaternion[-1, 0, 0, 0]` remains unevaluated.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know the `Pick[]` command, also the lengths of `ListQuad` and `sel` coincide with the numbers I know I should get.